Ansible Custom Facts for a Remote Node, not the Control Node - How is That Set Up?
A question about Ansible custom facts. I just started to learn those. Created and tested a couple on the Ansible Control Node lnx000.
For example, Ansible tells me the ogg_fact custom facts I put into a facts directory:
[root@lnx000 facts.d]# pwd
/etc/ansible/facts.d

[root@lnx000 facts.d]# ansible localhost -m ansible.builtin.setup | grep ogg_fact
                "ogg_fact_general": {
                    "ogg_fact_home": "/goldengate",
                    "ogg_fact_service_manager_port": "9000",
                    "ogg_fact_version": "19c"

But then I went to Remote Nodes that don't have Ansible installed, and of course, they don't have Ansible installed. Therefore, there is no custom facts directory on the Remote Host as on the Control Node lnx000.
[root@lnx000 facts.d]# ansible lnx072 -m ansible.builtin.setup | grep ogg_fact
[root@lnx000 facts.d]# 

If I try this directly on the Remote Host lnx072, it doesn't have Ansible.
[oracle@lnx072 tmp]$ ls -l /etc/ansible
ls: cannot access /etc/ansible: No such file or directory
[oracle@lnx072 tmp]$

So, the question is: How do I setup custom facts (all different ogg versions, homes, ports, etc) for all my Remote Nodes that don't have Ansible?
Thank you.

Answering my own question. It looks like all I had to do is to create the directory and the custom facts file on the Remote Node lnx072, even though it doesnt have Ansible there. The Control Node still finds the custom fact just fine. The 21c version reported below from the Control Node on the Remote Node is correct:
[root@lnx000 facts.d]# ansible lnx072 -m ansible.builtin.setup | grep ogg_fact
                "ogg_fact_general": {
                    "ogg_fact_home": "/goldengate",
                    "ogg_fact_service_manager_port": "9000",
                    "ogg_fact_version": "21c"
[root@lnx000 facts.d]#

Thanks for reading and answering.

Right, as the documentation states "To use facts.d, create an /etc/ansible/facts.d directory on the Remote Host"

By the way, you could also filter the ad-hoc and custom facts and would not need to use grep.
